# Is there a way to make Caps Lock led indicator to indicate current keyboard layout?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout, indicator

In Ubuntu 13.10 and older there were a keyboard layout option "use keyboard led to show alternative layout", so I could use it to have caps lock LED indicating current keyboard layout.[image] Now there is no keyboard layout preferences. I tried to use gnome-tweak-tool, but there is no that option too. Also I tried to type in console:

```
setxkbmap 'us,ru' -option 'grp:ctrl_shift_toggle,grp_led:caps,compose:menu'
```

and add

```
XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:caps"
```

to `/etc/default/keyboard`, but this doesn't work too.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options "['grp_led:caps']"
```

But I have two notes:

- until recently there was [a bug where the LED stays always lit](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/633), disregarding keyboard layout. [It was fixed today](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/merge_requests/2279) *(disclaimer: I fixed it)*, and it will be part of Gnome 42 release.
- You probably noted I omitted `grp:alt_shift_toggle` option. I advise against using it because that poorly integrated with gnome-shell and it conflicts with whatever keyboard layout switch shortcut is chosen in gnome-settings. In particular, I don't think per-window layout feature will work this way. And I certainly saw that a popup upon changing layout doesn't appear this way.

  Instead you should choose keyboard layout switch shortcut in Gnome settings manually.